# Shallow copy of two arrays in C

Tags: c, memory-management, copy

Is there a way to shallow copy the elements of a dynamically allocated array in C? Something like the following:

```c
int size = 2;
int *arr1 = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
int *arr2 = malloc(size*sizeof(int));

arr1[0] = 1; arr1[1] = 2; // {1, 2}
arr2[0] = 3; arr2[1] = 4; // {3, 4}

// shallow copy here s.t. memadress(arr1[i]) == memadress(arr2[i])
// ...

arr1[0] = -1; // arr1 = {-1, 2} AND arr2 = {-1, 4}
```

Comment: How about `memcpy` ? It can be used to copy the array content. But it will not create a permanent link between the arrays. So assigning `arr1[0] = -1` (after the copy) will not affect `arr2`.

Comment: What are those numbers in last comment supposed to mean? Do you expect that changing one element via `arr1` would also affect `arr2`? That is not at all what a shallow copy is about. As your arrays do not contain any pointers, it doesn't make any sense to talk about shallow or deep copying anyway.

Comment: You don't want to copy elements, you seem to want to create *references* between `arr1[0]` and `arr2[0]`. That's not possible using C. You can *emulate* references using pointers.

Comment: With all this said, what is the *actual* problem you need to solve? *Why* do you need a reference link between the two array elements? What is the underlying problem that's supposed to solve? Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's purely interest. I needed to perform a copy of the elements of one array to the elements of another array in some simulation code, and what i was simply doing was `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {arr1[i] = arr2[i];}`. And then I just was thinking about how that assignment just assigns the values, not references.

Comment: @wohlstad is `memcpy` preferred to simply doing an assignment loop over the elements of the arrays? `memcpy` seems to be quite concise in comparison, and presumably it could work with something like dynamically allocated arrays of structs (though i've never tried that).

Comment: @JaredFrazier preffered in what way ? The code will probably be shorter. Also it might be a bit faster, though this requires profiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Shallow" or "soft" copy typically just means copying a pointer but not the pointed-at data. As opposed to "hard" copy which also copies the pointed-at data. In your case, for example:

```
int *arr1 = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
int *arr2 = arr1; // "soft copy"

int* arr3 = malloc(size*sizeof(int);
memcpy(arr3, arr1, size*sizeof(int)); // "hard copy"
```

Or if you will:

```
int *arr1 = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
int *arr2 = malloc(size*sizeof(int));

arr1[0] = 1; arr1[1] = 2; // {1, 2}
arr2[0] = 3; arr2[1] = 4; // {3, 4}

free(arr2);
arr2 = arr1;
```

---

> arr1[0] = -1; // {-1, 2} AND arr2 --> {-1, 4}

This doesn't make much sense, since it implies a soft copy of the *elements* not of the *arrays*. Such a container is likely needlessly complicated and not very useful. It could be done with an array of pointers, however:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{

  int size = 2;
  int **arr1 = malloc(size*sizeof(int*));
  int **arr2 = malloc(size*sizeof(int*));

  // assign pointers to point at local compound literals:
  arr1[0] = &(int){1}; arr1[1] = &(int){2}; // {1, 2}
  arr2[0] = &(int){3}; arr2[1] = &(int){4}; // {3, 4}

  arr2[0] = arr1[0]; // "soft copy"
  *arr1[0] = -1;
  printf("arr1: {%d %d}\n", *arr1[0], *arr1[1]);
  printf("arr2: {%d %d}\n", *arr2[0], *arr2[1]);

  free(arr1);
  free(arr2);
}
```

Output:

```
arr1: {-1 2}
arr2: {-1 4}
```

But please avoid coming up with such obscure solutions just for the heck of it. Good programming = writing code as simple as possible.